# Very Quiet Sound

Tags: laptop, audio

I have a Toshiba Tecra A9 that has very, very quiet sound. This is not only in Windows XP but in Ubuntu too. I have re-installed the drivers but it's still quiet. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Same problem for me...It was OK with Windows XP but its sound is very low with Windows 7.How can I bosst my general laptop sound?I installed AC3 Booster but it only works while playing videos.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing to check first:

Do you have a hardware volume control anywhere? Is it turned down.

Comment: There is no hardware volume control.

Comment: I'm amazed at how often this happens though :)

Answer (score 0):

Some laptop speakers are just quiet, even if turned up as high as they'll go in  both hardware and software volume controls. The only thing you can do if this is the case is to plug in external speakers or headphones.

Some netbooks have the speakers underneath too, which doesn't help even if they are loud enough to start with.

Comment: No, this is not the case. We have plugged in three different kinds of headphones/earphones and all are really quiet. The speakers are on top.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, did you check the mixer settings? I've had it where the overall volume was all the way up, but if you opened the mixer, the wave output was quite low. There may be an equivalent in Ubuntu but I've never checked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Toshiba NB-200 and Windows XP and fixed the problem by installing Windows 7.